# Where does LastPass keep its local copy of the data?

Tags: synchronization, backup, passwords, lastpass

Just try it. Close your browser, disconnect your computer from internet, open the browser and try to access your [data on LastPass](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/security-of-data-handling-by-lastpass). It will be there. Because it's stored locally.

In [this forum topic](http://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?p=121719#p121719), Joe Siegrist says that LastPass always store the most updated local copy of our encrypted data. **I wonder if that data is stored at a single file and where**. So I could make backup copies of it and maybe even access it through [LastPass Pocket](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php).

I actually asked this same question in there, twice now, but still got no answer!

So, anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LastPass stores data in various places depending on your operating system and browser.

This information is taken from [this LastPass FAQ Article](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=425)

#### Windows

> - IE & Firefox
>
>   - `AppData%\..\LocalLow\LastPass\` or `%AppData%\..\Local
>       Settings\Application Data\LastPass\`
> - Chrome
>
>   - `%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>       Data\Default\databases\chrome-extension_hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd_0\`
> - Safari
>
>   - `%AppData%\..\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\Databases\safari-extension_com.lastpass.lpsafariextension-n24rep3bmn_0\`

#### OS X

> - Safari & Firefox
>
>   - `~/Library/Application Support/LastPass/`
> - Firefox (non-binary
>
>   - Firefox profile directory
> - Chrome
>
>   - `~/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/chrome-extension_hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd_0/`

#### Linux

> - Firefox
>
>   - `~/.lastpass/`
> - Chrome
>
>   - `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases/chrome-extension_hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd_0/`

> Firefox on other platforms utilizes
>   the Firefox profile directory. You can
>   back these directories up and they
>   will contain the latest copy of your
>   data. Be aware that on Windows,
>   Protected Storage is used to
>   additionally encrypt your data so
>   you'll need to ensure that your
>   Windows profile is also backed up.
>   Your data is also backed up at
>   LastPass.com, and a copy is on any
>   other device or computer you use so
>   this isn't required.
>
> Your data is also securely synced with
>   the LastPass servers. When you make
>   updates to your LastPass account,
>   whether in a browser plugin, a mobile
>   app, or the website, the updates are
>   reflected on the LastPass servers as
>   well. If your hard drive ever crashes,
>   or your laptop is stolen, you can
>   easily regain access to your accounts
>   by reinstalling the plugin
>   (https://lastpass.com/download.php)
>   and logging in with the same email and
>   master password.

Comment: we can easily "regain access" simply by logging in [*on the website*](https://lastpass.com/index.php?ac=1)! I had found those folders before, and it's good to now be sure the data I'm looking for must there somewhere. But I still don't know which files specifically are related to the question.

Comment: This is the main quote I was missing: "*You can back these directories up and they will contain the latest copy of your data*"