# Lastpass login information on multiple browsers

Tags: privacy, lastpass

I use Lastpass on two different browsers (Mozilla and Google Chrome) with two different ID's on each browser. I don't use the Firefox ID on Chrome and vice versa. But today something strange happened. After using Firefox and logging into Lastpass, my Firefox ID was automatically filled in Chrome. How is this possible?

AFAIK, Chrome cannot read anything that is stored by Firefox extensions or cannot read Firefox cookies. So is Lastpass really connecting my IP address with my login ID?

From [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15212/16367) it looks like there is a `~/.lastpass` directory which is used by the Firefox extension. So it looks like the Chrome extension is reading data from it. Is that possible? I'm on Linux.

**EDIT**: From [this answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1eb9158987e068f6&hl=en) on the Chrome discussion forums it seems very clear that Chrome extensions cannot read any external file, and can only access its local storage. I'm intrigued more now.

Comment: I've pinged their support to this question. Your usage is very unusual.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be using two different accounts but I believe LastPass is meant to sync with the other browsers. It's meant to allow you to switch browser to browser and computer to computer without much trouble. I'm assuming this is just one of the built in features. I'm not sure how they are going about syncing these two browsers therefore I did not put this as an answer.

Comment: @Fogest, I don't understand why this shouldn't be an issue. I use two *different* Lastpass accounts on two different browsers mainly for security/privacy reasons - throwaway accounts on Chrome and banking/cc information on Firefox. And I hardly think this a 'feature'. I'm concerned about the Chrome extension seeing my Firefox Lastpass ID, when I never use it on Chrome.

Comment: @pewfly Lastpass has a Univseral installer option. If you chose to install this, then that is probably the reason that Chrome can see it. If you simply installed ONLY the extension on each then it's odd that it's doing that.

Comment: @Fogest Nope, I am on Linux for which there is no universal installer. And I haven't used Lastpass on Windows PCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting in LastPass preferences called "`Share login state between other browsers`". It's located in the advanced section (list on the left). Uncheck it & save the settings.

Comment: Yes, I think this was the root of the problem. But I still wonder how Lastpass manages to share the login state between other browsers.

Comment: Local storage. I guess, it's that `.lastpass` folder.

Comment: AFAIK, your Lastpass vault is only stored once on a computer, regardless of the number of browsers using it.